# Responsive UI adding content at breakpoints

Tags: angular, responsive-design

I am trying to figure out best practices for adding content as the screen gets wider.

Many responsive guides shows how to re-order items and make them bigger or style the content differently using media queries.

But what if I want to have more content on the screen as the viewport gets bigger?

Bootstrap 4 has [Responsive utilities](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/) that can hide items at specific breakpoints. But it feels wrong. Items are only hidden.

Then there are the new Angular [Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) where you can have you code respond to breakpoint events. It's sound like a solution but there must be another way to handle this.

I have decided to use [ngIfMediaQuery](http://blog.radiant3.ca/2016/11/21/angular2-directive-responsive-conditional-output-using-css-media-query/) that's a thin wrapper around the [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) API, very easy to use.

```
<div *ngIfMediaQuery="'(min-width: 500px)'">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think most people use the equivalent of Bootstrap's show/hide utilities because it is simple, and easy for designers and front end devs to grok. You're right, though; it's loading things the client doesn't need. It does work for switching out background image URLs, but not really anything else.

On the front end js you can ajax or otherwise request scripts, styles, and content only after a check against viewport size or user agent. Eg, ajax in that gorgeous sidebar tag-cloud by putting it inside a function that gets run or not run based on viewport size (and re-checked on viewport events). This is probably the most flexible method, and can be as simple or complex as you want to make it--though it'll never be quite as simple as just dropping `hidden-xs` into your markup.

You could accomplish this on the back end in tandem with a front end script setting a session/cookie parameter. As far as I know there is no standard way for accomplishing this, and it's obviously less responsive to viewport changes like switching between landscape/portrait. Amazon does this and I'm pretty sure it's based on user agent.

A big consideration in all of this is SEO. You want to make sure Google isn't getting a face-full of js and nothing else. [They wrote a nice article on all of this](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/responsive-design), and you should probably go read it. For example, if you're going to serve different js based on user agent, they recommend adding an HTTP header that tells google to try crawling the site using different user agents.